# Retrieve information on clicked city in amCharts 4

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I am trying to implement a kind of like [animation along lines in amCharts 4](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/animations-along-lines/). I'm struggling to get the clicked city (`am4core.Circle`), it displays the tooltip information on hover, however, I am not able to get the data when the element is clicked.

Here's how I add the cities to my map:

```
//SetImageSeries()
let imageSeries = mapChart.series.push(new am4maps.MapImageSeries());
imageSeries.mapImages.template.propertyFields.longitude = `longitude`;
imageSeries.mapImages.template.propertyFields.latitude = `latitude`;
imageSeries.mapImages.template.propertyFields.url = `url`;

//AddCities
let cities = mapChart.series.push(new am4maps.MapImageSeries());
cities.mapImages.template.nonScaling = true;
cities.tooltip.background.strokeWidth = 0;
cities.cursorOverStyle = am4core.MouseCursorStyle.pointer;

let city = cities.mapImages.template.createChild(am4core.Circle);
city.radius = 10;
city.fill = am4core.color(`#d4a259`);

const addCity = (coords, title) => {
  let city = cities.mapImages.create();
  city.latitude = coords.latitude;
  city.longitude = coords.longitude;
  city.tooltipText = title;
  city.name = title;

  return city;
};

let genova = addCity({ 'latitude': 44.4056, 'longitude': 8.9463 }, `Genova`);
let amman = addCity({ 'latitude': 31.9539, 'longitude': 35.9106 }, `Amman`);
let sydney = addCity({ 'latitude': -33.8688, 'longitude': 151.2093 }, `Sydney`);
let london = addCity({ 'latitude': 51.5074, 'longitude': -.1278 }, `London`);
let barcelona = addCity({ 'latitude': 41.3851, 'longitude': 2.1734 }, `Barcelona`);
```

And here what I'm trying to get:

```
cities.events.on(`hit`, element => {
  console.log(element.target.dataItem);
  console.log(element.target.dataItem.dataContext);
});
```

`element.target.dataItem.dataContext` is `undefined`, however, the tooltip (or any other custom data) should be somewhere there.

Maybe I'm not putting the listener on the correct object...

The issue's similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55585394/how-to-get-value-of-bubble-in-amcharts-when-click-event-triggered) but their solution provided doesn't work in my case, and I guess is because of my way of loading data. I am open to change it if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [AmCharts 4 (Circle)](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/circle/) every circle element has its own click (hit) event so, they gave me the clue by:

```
chart.seriesContainer.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  console.log(ev.target.baseSprite);
});
```

So, you can add any custom value using `city.customValue=value` and retrieved using:

```
cities.events.on(`hit`, element => {
  console.log(element.target.customValue);
});
```

Listening on the event in the variable city itself also works:

```
aman.events.on(`hit`, element => {
  console.log(element.target.customValue);
});
```